# Scatter plot from table - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I plot a scatter that the input is the first row data of the table?

Script:

```
clc;
clear;
t1 = table({1;2;3;4;5;6},{1;2;3;4;5;6});
sz = 140;
scatter(t1(1,1),t1(1,2) ,sz,'d')
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your demo is wrong in 2 points:

Data generation, use square brackets for arrays.

```
t1 = table([1;2;3;4;5;6],[1;2;3;4;5;6]);
```

Data extraction, use curly brackets to extract from a table

```
scatter(t1{1,1},t1{1,2} ,sz,'d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may call the respective columns like below:

```
clear;
t1 = table([1;2;3;4;5;6],[1;2;3;4;5;6]);
sz = 140;
scatter(t1.(1),t1.(2) ,sz,'d')
```